# Audio streaming service to broadcast songs and metadata

Tags: audio, web-server, streaming

I am looking for a server side streaming service. It is important that the stream clients are not able to select which audio tracks to play, skip, seek, etc. but rather that the streaming service cycles through a directory of audio files similar to the *repeat album* functionality in iTunes or the *repeat all* functionality in VLC. Ideally, I would like to cycle through the audio files contained within a cloud service directory (AWS bucket or Firebase directory). It is essential that the streaming service could also broadcast metadata about the track currently being played, such as `artist`, `title`, and `duration`. As an added bonus, the service would also support the ability to broadcast live audio from an administrator's local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Icecast](https://icecast.org/):

"Icecast is a streaming media (audio/video) server which currently supports Ogg (Vorbis and Theora), Opus, WebM and MP3 streams.
It can be used to create an Internet radio station or a privately running jukebox and many things in between. It is very versatile in that new formats can be added relatively easily and supports open standards for communication and interaction.
Icecast is distributed under the GNU GPL, version 2."

The altervative is to look at the "jukebox" mode of music streaming apps like: Plex, Jellyfin, Navidrome etc.

edit:

Forgot to mention you can also look at [OBS](https://obsproject.com/).